# Contacts Updates in Android

Tags: android-contacts

I am working in an application which sync the contacts only with my application and my application sends its updated information to my server. But when a new contact add, update or delete, my app cannot determine the exact contact which is updated. I use cursor for it but sometimes cursor take more time for processing and update cannot occur, sometime it becomes crash and all contacts duplicate on my server. I am not using UI thread for it. I am using different thread for this purpose. Please help me for this problem.

Yours,

Answer (score 0):

At last I have found a way to do this by myself. I calculate my own hashes in my db and match them and if any hash is not found its means it is removed, add or modified. I send its key also and if a key value is exists in contacts its means it is modified if key is not find its mean deleted and if no hash occurs its meant new record entered.

If some one has better solution please suggest me.

Regards,

Comment: I have successfully use this technique for my application.